# How to list colors with rectangles and the color number in the middle of the rectangle in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Lately I have been struggling with listing colors in canvas using rectangles

What I have tried is:

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
const colors = ['aqua', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green'];
for(var i =0; i < colors.length; i++) {
// Color number
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillText(i+1, i*100, i*100);
// Color rect
ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
ctx.fillRect(i*100, i*100, 25, 25);
}
```

and i got this

[image: The result]

What i wanted to achieve:

[image: Tried to achieve]

So any ideas.

I'm not too good at canvas I just started using it lately.

Answer (score 1):

You're multiplying both `x` and `y` axis by `100`

```
ctx.fillRect(i*100, i*100, 25, 25);
              ^      ^
              x      y
```

instead you should keep the `y` value equal, if you want the rectangles on the same position on the y-axis

I think you should change 
`ctx.fillText(i+1, i*100, i*100);`
to
`ctx.fillText(i+1, i*100, i);`

and

`ctx.fillRect(i*100, i*100, 25, 25);`
to
`ctx.fillRect(i*100, i, 25, 25);`

To display the text inside the rectangle, you'll need to offset the text.

When your rectangle is `25` x `25` px, it's easy to put the text at the center of the rectangle, by adding to the `x` and `y` axis half of the size of the rectangle 12,5 px or 12px (rounded).

```
// first draw the rect
ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
ctx.fillRect(i*100, i*100, 25, 25);
// Color rect
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillText(i+1, i*100 + 12 , i*100 + 12);
//                        ^            ^   added an offset for the text there
```

Note that you should first render the rectangle, and then the text on top of it.

Comment: So I tried yours and the numbers is not in the middle of the rectangle so what is the fix?

Comment: I did not understand that you also wanted the numbers inside your rectangles, let me update the snippet for you

Comment: Thanks that's means a lot for me. God bless you!

Comment: There you go, let me know if this helped you

Answer (score 1):

I am putting a solution here, but it needs more OOP to avoid redundancy. I would leave that to you so you do more research and learn more.

HTML and CSS : We have three canvases here with different backgrounds and same height..

```
<canvas id="myCanvas_1" width="50" height="50"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color: yellow;">
</canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas_2" width="50" height="50"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color: red;">
</canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas_3" width="50" height="50"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color: green;">
</canvas>
```

**Javascript**: this controls what goes inside the canvas

```
var canvas_1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas_1");
var canvas_2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas_2");
var canvas_3 = document.getElementById("myCanvas_3");

var ctx = canvas_1.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("5",15,35);


var ctx = canvas_2.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("8",15,35);

var ctx = canvas_3.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("12",8,35);
```

**Complete snippet to run and try:**

```
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas_1" width="50" height="50"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color: yellow;">
</canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas_2" width="50" height="50"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color: red;">
</canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas_3" width="50" height="50"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color: green;">
</canvas>


<script>
var canvas_1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas_1");
var canvas_2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas_2");
var canvas_3 = document.getElementById("myCanvas_3");

var ctx = canvas_1.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("5",15,35);


var ctx = canvas_2.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("8",15,35);

var ctx = canvas_3.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("12",8,35);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do all of this in one canvas.. I really want it to be in one canvas

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what you mean by one canvas ? I gave you a solution that needs a little bit of work to make it better. I did it on purpose so you learn more searching for how to manipulate HTML with JS